# How to show the message taken from res.badRequest in Sails client

Tags: sails.js, ejs, bad-request

Recently I have encountered one issue that I want to show the message taken from `res.badRequest()`.

When error happens, my code is like:

```
var errMsg = 'Begin Date should be before End Date, please check';
sails.log.error(errMsg);   
return res.badRequest(errMsg);
```

but when I tried to get the error message in client, I failed, and here is my code in ejs:

```
<% if ( res.data ) { %><%=res.data%><% } %>
```

Where did I make mistake?
Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I use it in Angularjs client and works as documented https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/response-res/res-bad-request

`myService.sailsController()
  .then(function () {
    Alert.add({ type: "success", msg: "ok" });
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    Alert.add({ type: "danger",  msg: err.data +" [" + err.statusText + "]"});
  });`